# onSubmit javascript form event swap out image?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following input button code.  How do I alter this code to use a greyed out version of the button called `btn_nxt.png_hold.gif` once the submit occurs?

```
<input onsubmit="this.disabled=true;return true;" type="image" name="Insert" id="Insert" value="Insert" alt="Insert" src="images/btn_nxt.png"  />
```

Comment: onsubmit="this.disabled=true;return true;"

Comment: @ShadowWizard It was incorrect, I wasn't thinking straight, and when I noticed it you had already answered the question, so I deleted it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the picture when the button is clicked:

```
onclick="this.src='images/btn_nxt.png_hold.gif';"
```

The `onsubmit` belongs only to form elements.

Comment: i already have an onclick event...is there another event I can use that fires after onClick?

Comment: @Rocco no need for another event, just add the `this.src=...` to your existing `onclick` event.

Answer (score 2):

```
onclick="this.src='images/btn_nxt.png_hold.gif';this.disabled=true;"
```

Answer (score 0):

The propper solution is to add a class to the button upon submit. Using a style sheet you can then make any sort of modification to the button you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can also jQuery to manipulate it. its cleaner.

```
$("#Insert").live("click", function(){

    $(this).attr("src","path/tp/image.gif").attr("disabled", "disabled");

});
```

hope it helps.